# Find out which is the current background Drawable

Tags: android

inside my code, a View gets a new background:

```
myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.foo);
```

OK, it mustn't be "foo", there are a dozen different Drawables possible. That's causing my problem: Later I need to know, which of these Drawables is shown actually. But I'm not able to find out the resId neither the name of the background, and also I didn't find a way to compare these drawables:

```
Drawable myDraw = myView.getBackground();
Drawable compareDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foo);
```

They aren't equal. Hm. How can I find the current backgrund image?

Thanks in advance

TIA
Jo

Comment: try this : if(myDraw.equals(compareDraw); and tell us if it works

Comment: He just told you they aren't equal.

Comment: @Niek : i've seen the question dont worry , i've posted my comment to try the method equal(Object) because may be he did try the condition : myDraw == compareDraw , that's all

Comment: Well, of course I tried equal() - and even ==

Answer (score 2):

If you set your background why don't you keep a `class member` `int myBackground` that represents your currently background resource identifier. And each time you make

```
  myView.setBackgroundResource(R.id.myBack);
```

you also set :

```
  myBackground=R.id.myBack;
```

and in this way you always know the ID of your background resource.

Comment: I thought about something similar, using the tag attribute. But there should be a direct way, IMHO

Comment: comparing Drawables vs comparing some ints... it should be pretty direct

Answer (score 0):

Drawable is an abstract class, it can take many forms. From the documentation:

Though usually not visible to the application, Drawables may take a variety of forms:

> 1. Bitmap: the simplest Drawable, a PNG or JPEG image.
> 2. Nine Patch: an
>      extension to the PNG format allows it to specify information about
>      how to stretch it and place things inside of it.
> 3. Shape: contains
>      simple drawing commands instead of a raw bitmap, allowing it to
>      resize better in some cases.
> 4. Layers: a compound drawable, which
>      draws multiple underlying drawables on top of each other.
> 5. States: a
>      compound drawable that selects one of a set of drawables based on
>      its state.
> 6. Levels: a compound drawable that selects one of a set of
>      drawables based on its level.
> 7. Scale: a compound drawable with a
>      single child drawable, whose overall size is modified based on the
>      current level.

Internally I guess the bitmap may be the same, but the Drawable are of a different kind.